# Navigation Items not displaying on large screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, clip-path

My navigation items are not displaying on large screens, however on mobile devices they are displaying as expected. Can anyone assist me with a solution. I am suspecting that it has to do with the clip-path property, however i have tried to play around with it and haven't had any joy.I want the navigation items to display on large screens as it is displaying on mobile devices.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navBar {
  position: relative;
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #003300;
}

.navbrand {
  padding: .8em 0 0 1em;
  /*    margin: 2.5em 0;*/
}

.logo {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.navList {
  position: absolute;
  background: #003300;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%);
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding-top: 9em;
}

.navList.open {
  clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
  pointer-events: all;
}

.navItem {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
}

.navLink {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.navLink:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
}

.navLink:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
}

.navLink:nth-child(3) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
}

.navLink:nth-child(4) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
}

.navLink:nth-child(5) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
}

.navLink:nth-child(6) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
}

.navLink.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navLink:focus {
  color: #ff0000;
  opacity: .3;
}

.navLink:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
  opacity: .6;
}

.socialContact {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.socialLink {
  background: #fafafa;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 1em 0.625em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.socialFB {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #4267b2;
  padding: 1em;
}

.socialTwitter {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #1da1f2;
  padding: 1em;
}

.socialInsta {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #000;
  padding: 1em;
}

.hamburger-btn {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.hamburger-btn_burger {
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger-btn_burger::before,
.hamburger-btn_burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger-btn_burger::before {
  transform: translateY(-7px);
}

.hamburger-btn_burger::after {
  transform: translateY(7px);
}

.hamburger-btn.open .hamburger-btn_burger {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  background: transparent;
}

.hamburger-btn.open .hamburger-btn_burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.hamburger-btn.open .hamburger-btn_burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navBar {
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navList {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .navItem {
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .navLink {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 70px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbrand {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .hamburger-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  .socialContact {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo:focus {
    color: #ff0000;
    opacity: .1;
  }
  .logo:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">

  <div class="navbrand">
    <a href="#" class="logo">XandY Junior School</a>
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger-btn">
    <div class="hamburger-btn_burger"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="navList">
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="story.html" class="navLink">Our Story</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">Sports & Clubs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">Admissions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">Parents</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">BOSA</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="socialContact">
      <a href="#" class="socialLink"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f socialFB"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="socialLink"><i class="fab fa-twitter socialTwitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="socialLink"><i class="fab fa-instagram socialInsta"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct clip-path is on of the issues. But background is also an issue as its overlapping the existing content when clip-path is removed

I was able to see your "navlist" items using below css. Commented `background, clip-path & Padding`

```
.navList {
  position: absolute;
  /* background: #003300; */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%); */
  /* -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%); */
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* padding-top: 9em; */
}
```

Although, I'm not able to see the Navbar in mobile mode also, when I use dev-tools.

Comment: Still it hasn't solved the issue because it is not behaving as it should

Comment: You question was to help you understand why it was not showing up in larger screen and this answers that. And I would recommend you to format your CSS on your own based on this. Stack Overflow should be used as a source for help in debugging. If you're expecting more, please mention it in your question clearly on what your expected output should be.

Comment: I want some assistance with debugging what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it won't display on the large screens as per "bootstrap" for making the nav-bar not displayed with using display:none css class in the large screen.

so i will recommend for you to not use nav-bar from bootstrap and you can easily do it with html - css.

Comment: Even with using the HTML elements without classes, it still won't display.

Comment: yes, because you need to use some jQuery to show and hide items depend on your screen width in media query

Comment: @Tendekai check this link for the same case you have https://codepen.io/Slayer98/pen/qBEKeMJ

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hamburger-btn").click(function(){
  $(".navList").toggle();
});
});
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.navbrand {
display: block;
background: darkgreen;
padding: 10px;
}
.logo {
padding: 10px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
.hamburger-btn {
position: absolute;
top: -50px;
right: -3px;
background: darkgreen;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 150px;
}
.hamburger-btn_burger {
width: 30px;
height: 4px;
background: #fff;
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 77px;
right: 60px;
}
.hamburger-btn_burger::before{
position: absolute;
content: "";
width: 30px;
height: 4px;
background: #fff;
top: -8px;
z-index: 9;
}
.hamburger-btn_burger::after{
position: absolute;
content: "";
width: 30px;
height: 4px;
background: #fff;
bottom: -8px;
z-index: 9;
}
.navList{
display: none;
background: darkgreen;
padding: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 22px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;

}
.navList li{list-style: none;display: block;}
.navList li a{display: block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navBar">

  <div class="navbrand">
    <a href="#" class="logo">XandY Junior School</a>
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger-btn">
    <div class="hamburger-btn_burger"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="navList">
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="story.html" class="navLink">Our Story</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">Sports & Clubs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">Admissions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">Parents</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">BOSA</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navItem">
      <a href="#" class="navLink">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="socialContact">
      <a href="#" class="socialLink"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f socialFB"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="socialLink"><i class="fab fa-twitter socialTwitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="socialLink"><i class="fab fa-instagram socialInsta"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Can you please look at this code...

Comment: i have been trying to play around with what i thought are my solutions and it hasn't worked

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't understand. My example worked or not..??

Comment: can you give template image what's type of design you need. Because in your html I couldn't understand.

Comment: I don't have a template image. What i want is for the navigation items for example "About Us" to display on large screens because currently they are not displaying.